# How to implement a panel similar to iphone's new schedule in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

This panel includes a title and a listview. The listview can be scrolled. When the listview scrolls to the top, continue to slide down the list, and the entire panel will follow.

like this：

[image]

this panel include title （add event）and listview， now listview be scrolled。

[image]

Now, the list slides to the top, continuing to drop down the list, we can see the panel slide down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use draggableScrollableSheet in a stack to get this behaviour

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DraggableScrollableSheet'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [draggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90777
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60309
but, it not working when the lisview reverse

Comment: What's the error

Comment: when the listview is swiped to the top, the finger continues to slide, and the panel will not slide down, however, when the listview is swiped to the bottom, the finger continues to slide up, and the panel will drop. it is not expected

Comment: The list view should have enough items to do this behaviour. Try adding more items to it please